# Two-dimensional array full of garbage data... sometimes

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, initialization

I've been working on [this](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/diagonal-difference) simple coding challenge at HackerRank. I decided to implement my solution as a C function because any doing it in another language or in the main function itself seemed trivial.  I assumed that I'd muck up the array/pointer syntax a few times doing it this way and I'd have a chance to learn something.

This is my function :

```
int sum_diagonal(int n, int (*arr)[n]) {
   int lD, rD, sum;
   for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
       for(int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
           if (i == j) {
                rD += arr[i][j];
           }
           if ((i+j) == (n-1)) {
                lD += arr[i][j];
           }
       }
   }
   sum = abs(lD - rD);
   return sum;
}
```

And this is the `main()` function that calls it (the code to input the matrix was provided) :

```
int main(){
   int n; 
   scanf("%d",&n);
   int a[n][n];
   for(int a_i = 0; a_i < n; a_i++){
      for(int a_j = 0; a_j < n; a_j++){
         scanf("%d", &a[a_i][a_j]);
      }
   }
   //printf("why does this make it work?");
   int sum = sum_diagonal(n,a);
   printf("%d", sum);
   return 0;
}
```

Sometimes it works exactly as intended, and sometimes I get garbage output.  Stranger still, though, is the fact that if I uncomment that random `printf()` call in the main function it seems to work every time. What is going on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your code, you have defined

```
 int lD, rD, sum;
```

without initializing and then, you wrote

```
 rD += arr[i][j];
```

and

```
lD += arr[i][j];
```

`rD` and `lD` are automatic local variable and are not initialized. In the very first iteration itself, you're using them as to read the values from them (i.e., LHS of `+=`).

At that point of time, their content (values) are indeterminate. Using them, as you've done, invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Solution: Initialize your local variables always, like

```
 int lD = 0, rD = 0, sum= 0;
```

Comment: A silly mistake, oh well.  I just assumed I'd made a mistake passing my matrix into my function and was zoned in looking for that.  I'd be curious to know why the printf call made it work.  Interestingly, I tried it, and that worked locally with gcc but did not work with whatever compiler hackerrank was using.

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to use a non-constant value (n) to setup the size of your array. Thats not working in C. If you need a flexible size of your array, you should use malloc() to allocate memory.

```
int n; 
scanf("%d",&n); 
int a[n][n]; //n is a non-constant value.
```

Otherwise you could use a fix size of your array by using #define for example:

```
#define SIZE_OF_ARRAY 5

int a[SIZE_OF_ARRAY ][SIZE_OF_ARRAY ];
```

Comment: I don't think that's correct.  The value of n is defined at the time the array is being created because it has been read into memory by the scanf function.  The code compiled properly but gave random garbage data some of the time, the first answer solved the problem.